# jquery .html() invalid character "#"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently working on a script for a browser game I play that will add some buttons to the class "main-description". When I run the code though I get the error

```
SyntaxError: Invalid character: '#'
```

Here is a shortened version of what im trying to do

```
$( ".main-description" ).html("<button onclick='$(#chat_input).val(Text);$(#chat_submit).click();"'>Test</button>")
```

The code adds buttons to the page that adds text to a chatbox and then presses the send button. I have no idea whats going on and how I can fix it.

Comment: You probably need to escape your double quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to replace all the `“` and `”` characters with `"`. You will also have to ensure that you are passing a quoted string into the $ selector, as well as escaping any single or double quotes you find in the string (depending on what you used as the main delimiter)

```
$( ".main-description" ).html('<button onclick=\'$("#chat_input").val("Text");$("#chat_submit").click();"\'>Test</button>')
```

Comment: I am now getting SyntaxError: Invalid character '\u8216' and that character is 舖. How can I fix this?

Comment: That error might be happening elsewhere in your code. You may have to encode unicode characters (for example, try out `encodeURI('舖')` in your browser console)

Comment: Alright, in that case it means the markup contains an expression that does not have a matching set of quotes, or that expression contains unescaped  characters. I could review your code to see if there are any other syntax issues. To do so privately, you can create a chat room by going to http://chat.stackoverflow.com/ and inviting me.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like you need to escape some double-quotes. Try this:

```
$( ".main-description" ).html("<button onclick='$(\"#chat_input\").val(\"Text\");$(\"#chat_submit\").click();\"'>Test</button>")
```

Or at least that would cause problems in the code you originally posted. In your original code:

```
$( ".main-description" ).html("<button onclick='$("#chat_input").val("Text");$("#chat_submit").click();"'>Test</button>")
```

You can see from the weird syntax highlighting that something is not right. The double-quote before `..."#chat_input"...` will be interpreted as the closing quote for your input to `.html`, and it will all be downhill from there...

Answer (score 1):

You are missing qoutes surrounding selector strings and `"Text"` at `.val()` call. You can alternatively substitute passing `jQuery(html, attributes)` to `.html()` for `onclick` event handler attribute.

```
$(".main-description").html(
  $("<button>", {
    on:{click:function() {
                $("#chat_input").val("Text");
                $("#chat_submit").click()
              }
       },
    html:"Text"
  })
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```js
$( ".main-description" ).html("<button onclick=$('#chat_input').val('Text');$('#chat_submit').click();>Test</button>")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-description"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using extra quotes ("), use like below:

```
$( ".main-description" ).html("<button onclick='$(#chat_input).val(Text);$(#chat_submit).click();'>Test</button>")
```